# のになあ and wish/hope

Tags: usage

Is のになあ relevant to expressing a hope or wish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly, guy. 
You can refer that link: "http://www.tanos.co.uk/jlpt/skills/grammar/sentences/?grammarid=367"

Comment: When writing an answer please summarise the content of the link to include all relevant information right here (in case the link becomes unavailable). If you rather only link, you can leave a comment instead (or flag this post to be converted to a comment).